# iphone sdk In-App Purchase Error

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I struck in implementing In-app Purchase in my application. I need to purchase products using in-app purchase in my application. For this i added my products app_id with my iTunes a/c.

Here is my code reference,

Code:

**ViewController.m**

```
NSMutableArray *featuredappidArray; 


- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];
featuredappidArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 }

-(void)parseRecentPosts:(NSString*)responseString
{
    NSString *app_store_id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[post   objectForKey:@"app_store_id"]];
            NSLog(@"Recent Post app_store_id: %@",app_store_id);
            [featuredappidArray addObject:app_store_id];
            indexvalue=ndx;
 }

 - (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
 {

     [detailview Receivedappidurl:featuredappidArray idx:indexvalue];

 }
```

**DetailViewController.h**

```
-(void)Receivedappidurl:(NSMutableArray*)recentappidArray idx:(int)index;
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
NSMutableArray *appidArray;

-(void)Receivedappidurl:(NSMutableArray*)recentappidArray idx:(int)index
{
      NSLog(@"recentappidArray:%@",recentappidArray);
      appidArray=recentappidArray;
}
```

Now my console window receives all app_id's from my web service.

I added the necessary classes for In-App purchase like IAPHelper, InAppRageIAPHelper,MBProgressHUD,Reachability classes into my project.

```
-(IBAction)purchaseButton
{

   NSLog(@"appidarray:%@",appidArray);
   NSLog(@"pdt index:%d",productIndex);
   NSLog(@"APPLe indentifier:%@",[[appidArray objectAtIndex: productIndex] objectForKey:  @"app_store_id"]);
    [InAppRageIAPHelper sharedHelper].productIndex = productIndex;
    [[InAppRageIAPHelper sharedHelper] buyProductIdentifier:[[appidArray objectAtIndex: productIndex] objectForKey: @"app_store_id"]];

    self.hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
    _hud.labelText = @"Buying Book...";
    [self performSelector:@selector(timeout:) withObject:nil afterDelay:60*5];
}
```

Here when am tapping the buy button my app getting crashed and getting the following error,
" Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9154ad0' "

I referred many tutorials.How to purchase using this? Please help me out of this. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is crashing your code

```
[[appidArray objectAtIndex: productIndex] objectForKey:  @"app_store_id"]
```

This most likely is because `[appidArray objectAtIndex: productIndex]` returns a string, and not a dictionary.

First step: you need to load the items from the store like this:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:yourProductIdentifiers autorelease]; 
productsRequest.delegate = self;
[productsRequest start];
```

PS. you can find your product identifiers on the web, in the Manage InApp Purchases section

after doing this, you will receive a list of products, and to purchase any of them:

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

Comment: ok fine. All the app_id's are in my array. Now how can i proceed with? to make my products purchase?